# Flag rows in matrix that contain the same set of values

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix of integers

```
m <- rbind(c(1,2),
           c(3,6),
           c(5,1),
           c(2,1),
           c(6,3))
```

and I am looking for a function that takes this matrix as input and outputs a vector `flag` with `length(flag) == ncol(m)` that assigns the rows that contain the same set of integers the same unique (let's say integer) value.

For the above example, the desired output would be:

```
flag <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2)
```

So rows 1 and 4 in`m` get the same flag 1, because they both contain the same set of integers, in this case {1, 2}. Similarly, rows 2 and 5 get the same flag.

The solution should work for any number of columns.

The only thing I could come up with is the following approach ...

```
FlagSymmetric <- function(x) {

  vec_sim <- rep(NA, nrow(x)) # object containing flags
  ind_ord <- ncol(x)

  counter <- 1

  for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {

    if(is.na(vec_sim[i])) { # if that row is not flagged yet, proceed ...

      vec_sim[i] <- counter # ... and give the next free flag

      for(j in (i+1):nrow(x)) {

        if( (i+1) > nrow(x) ) next # in case of tiny matrices

        ind <- x[j, ] %in% x[i, ] 
        if(sum(ind)==ind_ord) vec_sim[j] <- counter # if the same, assign flag

      }

      counter <- counter + 1

    }
  }

  return(vec_sim)
}
```

... which does what I want:

```
> FlagSymmetric(m)
[1] 1 2 3 1 2
```

If `n = nrow(m)` this needs 1/2 n^2 operations. Of course, I could make it much quicker by writing this in C++, but this only alleviates my problem to some extent, because I am working with matrices with a potentially huge number of rows.

I guess there must be a smarter way of doing this.

**EDIT:**

Additional, more general example (sorting row and pasting to character string not possible):

```
m2 <- rbind(c(1,112),
           c(11,12),
           c(12,11),
           c(112,1),
           c(6,3))

flag2 <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3) # desired output

FlagSymmetric(m2) # works
[1] 1 2 2 1 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you only have numeric data in your matrix.

First converting the matrix to dataframe,

```
m <- data.frame(m)
```

We can `sort` every row and `paste` them together. Convert them to `factor` and then to `numeric` to get unique numbers for every combination

```
m$flag <- as.numeric(factor(apply(m, 1, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = ""))))
m

#  X1 X2 flag
#1  1  2    1
#2  3  6    3
#3  5  1    2
#4  2  1    1
#5  6  3    3
```

**EDIT**

The above solution does not work for every combination as explained in the new example. To differentiate between each number, as @d.b commented we can use any non-empty collapse argument. For updated example,

```
as.numeric(factor(apply(m2, 1, function(x) paste0(sort(x), collapse = "-"))))

#[1] 1 2 2 1 3
```

Comment: Is `m <- data.frame(m)` is necessary?

Comment: @d.b ahh..not necessary. Its so that I am so used to working on dataframes. `apply` anyways convert it into matrix.